# Winforms Designer, C# Project with VC++ references, working directory issues

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, projects-and-solutions, windows-forms-designer

I'm working in a solution with ~100 project (of mixed C# Winforms, VC++ Winforms, and Unmanaged C).

I have a project, named 'DatafiltersControls' (C#), which has a references to a project named 'DatafiltersTypes' (VC++), shown below is the xml entry for the specific reference.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\DatafiltersTypes\DatafiltersTypes.vcxproj">
  <Project>{360679FF-815C-4B39-8E5A-62C0D2A6DB31}</Project>
  <Name>DatafiltersTypes</Name>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

Now, the problem: "The designer will only load my controls under certain circumstances".  After doing a lot of research, i've broken it down to my development environment, and the way I open my solution.  My build environment is created from inside a dos window, which will subst a new drive (P:), mapped to a directory.

After my directory is created:

- If my prompt is has "p:\common" as the current working directory, and type common.sln, all designers work great with no issue.  This was the current working directory when I initially set that reference in the first place.
- If I doubleclick on common.sln from explorer, and then try to open a 'complicated' form, I get the following error: *Could not load file or assembly 'DatafiltersTypes, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified*
- If my prompt has "p:\" or any other directory as the CWD, and then invoke "p:\common\common.sln", the designer breaks on complex forms (same as above)

I believe the specific problem is this: my references where added relatively, based on the CWD when visual studio was opened.  From that point on, the designer breaks on any 'complicated' form, because the search path is based on the cwd.

If needed, I can define 'complicated', I have the exact circumstances.  My ideal solution would to allow my references to be based on the root of the drive (its a constraint developers at my company already have anyways).  For instance, instead of

....\build\output\datafilterstypes.dll, I want \build\output\datafilterstypes.dll as my reference.

Its important to note that: **Everything compiles just fine regardless of my working directory when I load devenv, its just the designer.**

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To add, I have the same issues if the

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the designer cannot load C++ dll's that aren't pure.  Convert any project that will directly, or indirectly, a C++ dll to be pure.